# Horizontal Distribution Without left or right margins

Tags: html, css, layout

I am trying to style a horizontal distribution ( where I wont know how many elements will be in the row ). I have found exactly what I am looking for in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/jwJBd/ but I would rather if there was some way to not have a left margin to the first and right margin to the and last elements of the row ( while keeping the other margins) ... essentially what I want is for the first and last elements to line up with the extremes of the layout but having spacing between them ).

Is there any way to do this? I have looked at all the questions related to this subject on SO but none seem to fit my HTML exactly ... ( I have no access to change the html as it is a plugin, unless I change it with javascript, or re-write the plugin which I'm not going to do ) I can use javascript if I have to but I would much rather do it with CSS. 
Just to avoid confusion my layout is a portfolio layout and not a menu.

**HTML**

```
<div style="width: 100%">
    <ul id="horizontal-style">
        <li><a href="#">Nav Item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Short Item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Really Long Nav Item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Nav Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another Link</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#horizontal-style {
    display: table;
    width: 100%
}
#horizontal-style li {
    display: table-cell;
}
#horizontal-style a {
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid red;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 5px;
    background: #999
}

div {
    background: #ccc
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`first-child` works in all modern browsers and back to IE7.0. [I'm pretty sure it's safe to use.](http://caniuse.com/css-sel2)

Modify your CSS like the following:

```
#horizontal-style a {
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid red;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 0 0 5px; /* change here*/
    background: #999
}

/*add this*/
#horizontal-style li:first-child a {
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cwalkdawg/Hnmww/)

[Another jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hnmww/2/) with multiple rows and varying element amounts.

Comment: No I cant use first child or last child because I wont know how many are in a row as it's a responsive design and the number per row depends on the width of the browser. I actually made that clear in my question, so I don't know why you are suggesting it ... or am I missing something; does your code in some reconcile this with my scenario. It seems though that you think I want to avoid using first/last child for browser compatibility reasons but I never said anything about that.

Comment: mmm ...My design needs to span two rows if the first row gets overpopulated. I have the entire thing wrong though and that's where the confusion arises. The snippit I found will never work for what I want it to do because it always keeps everything on a single line, and for some reason I assumed it didn't ... so I suppose in that sense your answer does answer my question, but actually it's not the question I thought I was asking. So what I'm going to do is modify my question so it matches your answer a bit better, award you the tick and start again from scratch looking for some different code.

Comment: no it was my own mistake really ... but yes I tend to agree. I've been using html and css on and off since 1999 and every day I seem to find another thing I thought I understood years ago but it turned out I didn't.

Answer (score 1):

> I would rather if there was some way to not have a left margin to the first and right margin to the and last elements of each row ( while keeping the other margins) ... essentially what I want is for the first and last elements to line up with the extremes of the layout but having spacing between them ) . Is there any way to do this?

Let the first and last element of each line *have* their outer margins – and hide them, by giving the `UL` element a corresponding *negative* margin to both sides.

Comment: Thanks. could you read the comment I made to ChristopherW's answer just now. ( actually negative margin on both sides of the parent element has given me an idea, thanks )